# Firebase Crashlytics doen't recognize my app

Tags: android, firebase

Hi I'm trying to configure Firebase Crashlytics without success and would like to get some help.

It worked in the past and suddenly the console of Firebase resets

**This is the current situation**

[image: This is the current situation]

I did all the steps according to documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android&authuser=1#add-plugin

**Step 1:** Registration of the application in Firebase Crashlytics

[image]

**Step 2.1:** Gradle Project Level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Step 2.2 and Step 3:** Gradle App Level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-api' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.willingapp.willing"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30

        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Base libs
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.main.resources:javamail:5.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    //Google Places
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'

    // Google SMS API Retriever
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.1'

    //HTTP Communication
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'

    //Text Handler
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.8'

    //RTL Support ViewPager
    implementation 'com.duolingo.open:rtl-viewpager:2.0.0'

    //Image Handler
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:4.1.2'

    //Tags
    implementation 'com.github.adroitandroid:ChipCloud:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.RahulSDeshpande:ChipCloud:3.0.6'

    //Json Handlers
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

**Step 4:** The Crash I did and nothing happend

[image]

Comment: What about the JSON file? Added that as well? Just making sure.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention it

Comment: There is a chance that the crashlytics is not enabled for the debug build. See the following link to enable crashlytics for the debug build as well. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android&authuser=1#enable-debug-logging